# How would i check if a user does not have a webcam?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to make a video chat platform and I can not work out how to detect if a user does not have a webcam available and if they don't, it sets the video feed to a static image or name and profile picture.

here is my current way of getting the webcam:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(with_video).then((stream) => {
    addVideoStream(myVideo, stream);

    myPeer.on('call', (call) => {
        call.answer(stream);
        const video = document.createElement('video');
        call.on('stream', (userVideoStream) => {
            addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream);
        });
    });

    socket.on('user-connect', (userId) => {
        connectToNewUser(userId, stream);
        join.play();
    });
});
```

addVideoStream:

```
function addVideoStream(video, stream) {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
        video.play();
    });
    videoGrid.append(video);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need navigator.getUserMedia,

try this function.

```
function hasUserMedia() { 
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia 
|| navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia; 
return !!navigator.getUserMedia; 
}
```

and should be called something like

```
if (hasUserMedia()) { 
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(callConstraints)
    .then(gotStream)
    .catch(function(e) {
        alert('getUserMedia() error: ' + e.name);
    });
}
else{
    alert('hasUserMedia() error: ');
}
```

additionally, you might need to check the permission if Cam is available but the user has not given permission. and for that, you can use the following function.

```
checkForVideoAudioAccess = async () => {
try {
    const cameraResult = await navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'camera' });
    isCameraAccessGranted = cameraResult.state !== 'denied';
    const microphoneResult = await navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'microphone' });
    isMicrophoneAccessGranted = microphoneResult.state !== 'denied';
} 
catch(e) {
    console.error('An error occurred while checking the permissions', e);
}
return true;
```

}

Comment: Im using that now, my current issue is trying to get an image to load where the video would be. PeerJS is bugging out when i dont use a video for the feed

Answer (score 1):

I hope this javascript library [DetectRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/DetectRTC) solve your problem.

```
if (DetectRTC.hasWebcam === false) {
    alert('Please install an external webcam device.');
}
```

You can also check live demo [here](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/DetectRTC/).

Comment: i am planning to try and use vanilla js. is there a way to do it in vanilla?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a `.catch()` block to your `getUserMedia()` call.  That way, you can handle the error if there is no device, or if the user disallows media capture.

Comment: how would i set the feed to an image then? the media also uses mic

Comment: @ExiteGalacTix Set the poster image of the video element.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: peerjs doesn't like when i put a video or image as my video feed. [error](http://img.galactix.xyz/eomj0dgcd9yekwnwwgetfru7k.png)
 [code](http://img.galactix.xyz/pqwikcmfrtw485mfwdhmp9rk1.png)

Comment: @ExiteGalacTix That's a string, not a stream.  You really don't want to send a static image as a stream.  If for some reason you needed to do that, you'd have to draw the image to a canvas and use a capture stream.  But, there are severe limitations to this, not to mention a large waste of bandwidth.  What I was saying was use the `poster` attribute of the `<video>` element, to display an image if there is no video stream.

Comment: ah, ok. would i have to do something like `new Video("image video location")`?

Comment: my problem is that peerjs needs to get a track from the video but an image does not have a track

Comment: What I'm saying to you is that if it's a static image, you really *don't* want to send a video track.  Send the image instead.  Otherwise, you'll be wasting a bunch of bandwidth on a relatively low quality image, as well as the CPU overhead of encoding a fixed canvas.  Additionally, the canvas method stops working as soon as the browser loses focus.  But, if you just send the image instead, you can display it directly.  It will look a lot better, and be simpler.

Comment: I physically cant. peerjs does not allow it

Comment: You're building the chat application, but you're saying the other side doesn't know how to look up the profile picture for the other user?  Even if that were the case, you could send the data over the peer data connection.

Answer (score 1):

Try a catch block. Here's mine

```
async function webcamCheck() {
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) { // browser support
        let stream = null;
        try {
            stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true});
            showVideoControls();
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.play();
        } catch(err) {
            setError(err.name + ": " + err.message);
        }

        if (!checkForErrors()) console.log('Webcam found :)');
    }
    else {
        setError("This browser does not support webcam technology");
    }
}
```